# How to check condition based on a variable match

Tags: r, variables, comparison, tidyverse, variable-names

Say that I have these data:

```
data <- tibble(person=c("Jack", "Jill", "Bill"), pet=c("dog", "cat", "zebra"), pet_cat=c(0,1,0), pet_dog=c(0,1,1), pet_llama=c(1,1,1))

  person pet   pet_cat pet_dog pet_llama
  <chr>  <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
1 Jack   dog         0       0         1
2 Jill   cat         1       1         1
3 Bill   zebra       0       1         1
```

What I want to do is, for each person, to first find out which pet they have (Jack has a dog) and then go to the column that includes this pet (for Jack, this is the `pet_dog` column). And then make a new column, `match`, that copies the value from the `pet_` column (for Jack, this is `0` because `pet_dog`'s value for `Jack` is 0). Not sure if this is necessary, but one way to think about this is that `pet` refers to the `person`'s preference for a pet and the `pet_` columns refer to the availability of the pet in the pet store, and `match` tells if the person is able to buy the pet of their preference.

Furthermore, in some cases, there will not be a `pet_` column matching the `person`'s `pet`. In these cases, the `match` should be `0`.

Note that for one person, say `Jill`, the other people's values are totally irrelevant, as are the `pet_` columns that do not correspond to `Jill`'s `pet` value.

This is the desired result:

```
data_want <- tibble(person=c("Jack", "Jill", "Bill"), pet=c("dog", "cat", "zebra"), pet_cat=c(0,1,0), pet_dog=c(0,1,1), pet_llama=c(1,1,1), match=c(0, 1, 0))

  person pet   pet_cat pet_dog pet_llama match
  <chr>  <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 Jack   dog         0       0         1     0
2 Jill   cat         1       1         1     1
3 Bill   zebra       0       1         1     0
```

How can I do this?

Note that I think it will involve putting the person's `pet` value into a variable using something like `get` or `assign` combined with `paste0`, then going to this column and pulling the relevant value and putting it in `match`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/)

1. Reshape to long format with [`pivot_longer`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html)
2. Subset the rows where `value` is 1
3. Create a logical column by matching the substring from 'pet' with 'name' column - [`str_detect`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.4.0/topics/str_detect)
4. Grouped by 'pet', check if there are `any` TRUE in 'match', coerce it to binary (`+`)
5. Join with original dataset - `right_join`
6. If we want to keep the order from original data, create a sequence column (`row_number()`) and order the rows (`arrange`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
data %>%
     pivot_longer(cols = contains('_')) %>% 
     filter(value == 1) %>% 
     mutate(match = str_detect(name, pet)) %>%
     group_by(pet) %>%
     summarise(match = +(any(match))) %>% 
     right_join(data %>% 
                   mutate(rn = row_number())) %>% 
     arrange(rn) %>% 
     select(names(data), match)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  person pet   pet_cat pet_dog pet_llama match
  <chr>  <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl> <int>
1 Jack   dog         0       0         1     0
2 Jill   cat         1       1         1     1
3 Bill   zebra       0       1         1     0
```

---

Or may use [`rowwise`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/rowwise.html)

1. Create the `rowwise` attribute - grouped by row
2. Use [`c_across`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/c_across.html) to create a logical vector i.e. where value is 1
3. Use the logical index to subset the column names that `starts_with` 'pet_'`,
4. Remove the substring 'pet_' - [`str_remove`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.4.0/topics/str_remove)
5. Create a single string by concatenating them - `str_c`
6. Remove the group attribute (`ungroup`) and use `str_detect` to detect if the 'pet' column values have a match with regex pattern created

```
data %>%
   rowwise %>% 
   mutate(match =  str_c(str_remove(names(select(cur_data(), 
      contains('_')))[c_across(contains("_")) == 1], ".*_"), 
          collapse="|")) %>%
   ungroup %>% 
   mutate(match = +(str_detect(pet, match)))
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  person pet   pet_cat pet_dog pet_llama match
  <chr>  <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl> <int>
1 Jack   dog         0       0         1     0
2 Jill   cat         1       1         1     1
3 Bill   zebra       0       1         1     0
```

---

Or using `base R`

1. Select the column names that contains 'pet_' (nm1)
2. Create a row/column index based on sequence of rows and `match`ing the substring of column name with 'pet' column
3. Get the corresponding elements from the selected columns of data with the use of 2 as a `matrix`
4. Replace the elements that are NA (i.e. no match) to 0

```
nm1 <- names(data)[startsWith(names(data), "pet_")]
data$match <- as.data.frame(data[nm1])[cbind(seq_len(nrow(data)), 
       match(data$pet, sub("pet_", "", nm1)))]
data$match[is.na(data$match)] <- 0
```

-output

```
data
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  person pet   pet_cat pet_dog pet_llama match
  <chr>  <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 Jack   dog         0       0         1     0
2 Jill   cat         1       1         1     1
3 Bill   zebra       0       1         1     0
```